# Unable to configure Twitter feed in Drupal site

Tags: iframe, drupal-7, block, drupal-views, twitter-feed

I have a website in Drupal and I wants same look of twitter widget as in https://www.stanford.edu/ .

There is a module also available in Drupal for Twitter i.e "Drupal feed".

https://www.stanford.edu/ site is mentioned in this module also.

So please help me out so that i can get same look..

Thanks in Advance..

Note : The code i am using is given below.

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/tweettestwidget" data-widget-id="603417854055034880" data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent" data-tweet-limit="1" data-conversation="none">Tweets by @tweettestwidget</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried the Twitter module https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Twitter module to create a similar twitter feed.
https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter

You can see the feed I created here http://gekkos.com

You can then display the Twitter feed using a View. Then use Views templates to style the output.

E.g. My Views template file was *views-view-fields-tweets--block.tpl.php*

```
<div class="tweet">
<p><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/<?php print $fields['screen_name']->content;?>"><?php print $fields['screen_name']->content;?></a> <?php print $fields['text']->content;?> - <em><?php print $fields['created_time']->content;?></em></p>
```

Then just style the output using CSS.